# Как отобразить спецсимволы в android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Мне нужно подписать единицы измерения на шкале прибора: кгс/см квадратный. Разработка в Android Studio. Подскажите, как можно отобразить сам символ квадрата. Как отобразить спецсимволы в интернете я нашла. Но там нет квадрата.

Comment: На, копируй: "кгс/см²"

Comment: Извините, не понимаю. У меня отдельный класс, который рисует  разные шкалы и в качестве параметров ему задаются, в том числе, единицы измерения.

Comment: Символы ² и ³ - это не спец. символы, а самые обычные. Они есть во всех шрифтах и могут быть использованы, в том числе и в xml без ограничений

Comment: @lsillarionov Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<string name="kgs_sm_2">кгс/см&#178;</string>
```

Я использую десятичный код, Ваш пример будет выглядить так.

Answer (score 3):

```
<string name"kgs_sm_2">кгс/см<sup>2</sup></string>
```

XML поддерживает простейшие `HTML` теги

Comment: К сожалению, данный вариант привел к следующему отображению: "кгс/см2".

Comment: @Bolonat, я сам попробовал прежде, чем отвечать. Вы, возможно, используете его как-то извращенно

Comment: Боюсь, у меня не такая богатая фантазия... :)

Comment: @Bolonat, Я говорю о том, что отображается это неправильно только потому, что вы неправильно используете. Как именно - вы никому не рассказали.

Comment: @ metalurgus, использую абсолютно также как вариант, предложенный @Shwarz Andrei. Его вариант отображает "кгс/см²", а Ваш - "кгс/см2"

Comment: @Bolonat, Значит ему повезло, и он угадал, как же именно вы используете. Мне не повезло, я не угадал. Но это совершенно не моя вина в том, что вы не хотите разбираться в своей проблеме. Мне оно тоже 300 лет надо в таком случае.

Comment: textView1.setText(getString(R.string.kgs_sm_2));

Comment: В данном случае вместо getString() нужно использовать getText(), либо сразу setText(R.string.kgs_sm_2), тогда будет работать.

Comment: Да, действительно, если написать setText(R.string.kgs_sm_2), то цифра 2 приподнимается над строкой. Однако, обратите внимание на размер цифры 2 в каждом из вариантов: "кгс/см²" и  "кгс/см2". Во втором случае цифра 2 имеет размер как заглавная буква и когда она отображается выше, то часть цифры выходит за пределы верхней границы строки и усекается, что неприемлемо. Кроме того, если указать в разметке android:text="@string/kgs_sm_2", то в дизайнере, подчеркиваю, только в дизайнере, для любых виртуальных устройств и для любых версий API по-прежнему отображается "кгс/см2".

Answer (score 1):

HTML теги в данном случае не нужны. Символы ² и ³ можно использовать без каких-либо ограничений. Их начертание есть во всех шрифтах на android и проблем не возникнет.

Например, в XML:

```
<string name="unit_kgf_cm2">кгс/см²</string>
```

или в коде:

```
textView.setText("кгс/см²");
```

Вместо символа можно использовать его код U+00B2 (178).

В XML:

```
<string name="unit_kgf_cm2">кгс/см&#178;</string>
```

В коде:

```
textView.setText("кгс/см\u00B2");
```

Но по мне так такой вариант только ухудшает читаемость.

В данных случаях это обычные строки и работают все соответствующие операции. Например, не возникает проблем при такой конкатенации:

```
String value = "0.5 " + getString(R.string.unit_kgf_cm2);
textView.setText(value);
```

Конечно, можно использовать и HTML теги:

```
<string name"kgs_sm_2">кгс/см<sup>2</sup></string>
```

Но в этом случае это уже будут не обычные строки, а текст с форматированием и это нужно будет везде учитывать. Предыдущий пример уже будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
CharSequence value = TextUtils.concat("0.5 ", getText(R.string.unit_kgf_cm2));
textView.setText(value);
```

Comment: Я думаю, что нужно добавить, что ввести надстрочный символ можно используя Таблицу символов Windows. Нажать "Пуск". В поле "Найти" ввести "Таблица символов" и в списке результатов дважды щелкнуть "Таблица символов". Выбрать нужный символ и скопировать его в свою строку.